# Sorting a List<object[]> by datetime

Tags: c#, .net

I Have this list:

```
List<object[]> lstMessaggi = new List<object[]>();
```

A sample element in this list is an array of 3 objects:

1)a string

2)a datetime

3)a string

My question is:how can i order "lstMessaggi" by ascending Datetime values?

Comment: Do you have to use `object[]`? If you have control over the type, you may consider using a ValueTuple or an anonymous object.

Comment: I would create a List of my custom type with three properties included, instead of `object`!

Comment: Use a tuple at least, unless you want to make this as unreadable and as difficult to work with as possible.

Comment: I don't have to use object[], i just thought it was a rapid solution

Comment: @PaoloAmato Do it once and do it right. You can either use a record (.Net 5 yay!), ValueTuple, create a class or struct to fit your data. Any of those are better soluctions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this data structure seems like a really bad idea. It's calling out for a class definition, or at very least a tuple.

But, assuming the elements in the list are consistent, you can do this:

```
List<object[]> lstMessaggi = new List<object[]>();
lstMessaggi = lstMessaggi.OrderBy(m => (DateTime)m[1]).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain me why this is a bad idea? what is the problem with List<object[]>?

Comment: Because **anything** can be in an `object[]`. You leave yourself open to bugs you could (should!) have caught with the compiler that won't show up until runtime. You make yourself need to do extra type casting and index lookups everywhere. You lose semantic and intellisense help with understanding how the objects are used, making code **much** harder to read, understand, and maintain.

Comment: Ok, i perfectly understood what you mean. Thanks for everything. Thanks to everyone other too. I will use a custom class.

Comment: Btw, it says Orderby is not defined, even if intellisense automatically shows me the name of this extension.

Comment: @Paolo add `using System.Linq;` to the top

Comment: Instea of using object[] let c# figure out the type by its own with: `var lstMessaggi = lstMessaggi.Orderby(m => (DateTime)m[1]).ToList();` some IDE's like VS will work better with this (in terms of autocomplete)

Comment: I already added the using directive, but still not working

Comment: `Orderby` is wrong, should be `OrderBy` just a little casing issue. @JoelCoehoorn I went ahead and corrected that in your post.

Comment: Yes it was an error in writing. Forgive me, i am a noob ahahah.